# Why image source get unknown?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In this below code if condition is true then work well but if condition is false looking weird image src...

**Here down my code**

```
<img th:src="${(profileData.profile != null) ? profileData.profile : '../images/users/app-store.png'}" alt="" class="img-responsive profile-photo" />
```

**Inspect**

```
<img src(unknown) alt="" class="img-responsive profile-photo">
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Comment: Uh... it looks like the link to you image `'../images/users/app-store.png'` is wrong.  Are you sure it's where you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions

```
<img th:src="${(profileData.profile != null)} ? ${profileData.profile} : '../images/users/app-store.png'" alt="" class="img-responsive profile-photo" />
```

Hint: check your closing bracket `}` in your initial condition